# Excel: FILTER two columns from a table and output in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I have a function that outputs filtered contents from several tables that are combined using `VSTACK()`.

As can be seen in the example of what I have now, this works but only outputs the 'Name'. Is it possible to instead output 'Name Surname' in the same column, as in the example of what I wish to have?

##### What I have now.

```
=LET(v, VSTACK(TableA, TableB), FILTER(INDEX(v, , 1), INDEX(v, , 3)=$I$2, "No students at this result"))
```

[image]

##### What I wish to have.

[image]

I have tried to simple `CONCAT()` the columns that I wish to output, but the `FILTER()` function accepts an array as it's first argument, so this fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `CONCAT()` use `Ampersand` --> `&` to combine two arrays like as shown in the example:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     v, VSTACK(TableA, TableB),
     FILTER(INDEX(v, , 1)&" "&INDEX(v,,2), INDEX(v, , 3)=$I$2, "No students at this result"))
```

---

Also since you have access to `VSTACK()` then use `TAKE()` function to make the formula bit shorter:

```
=LET(
     _v,VSTACK(TableA,TableB),
     FILTER(TAKE(_v,,1)&" "&INDEX(_v,,2),TAKE(_v,,-1)=I2,"No students at this result"))
```

---

Another way is passing a custom `LAMBDA()` calculations using `BYROW()` function :

```
=LET(
     _v,VSTACK(TableA,TableB),
     _f, FILTER(TAKE(_v,,2),TAKE(_v,,-1)=I2,"No students at this result"),
     BYROW(_f,LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(" ",1,x))))
```

---

But note here is caveat when using `TEXTJOIN()` function, as per **MSFT Documentations** if the resulting string exceeds **32767** characters (cell limit), returns the `#VALUE!` error.

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `&` does exactly what I was looking for. However, I don't think I can use `TAKE()` as in reality I have more than 3 columns, and 'Result' is somewhere in the middle. But useful to know of it's existence.

Comment: @DavidGard ah ok, I wasn't aware of that, but thought it would be useful. Then `INDEX()` is your best bet. Thanks btw! Also there are few new functions like `CHOOSECOLS()` or `CHOOSEROWS()` then `TEXTBEFORE()` & `TEXTAFTER()`